# pyqt GUI crashing issue during serial communication with arduino

Tags: python, arduino

I have build a GUI using python (PYQT) that will communicate with the arduino. But I am facing an issue. When I press the (get data) button in the given GUI, the GUI is going to crash and restart it. I have attached the GUI pic, python code and the arduino code. If anyone have knowledge about it please help me in this I will be very thankful.

**Python code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSerialPort
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QTextEdit, QPushButton,  QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QFrame,QComboBox, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
import serial
#serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM4", baudrate=115200,bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
import time
import sys
str2="getdata"

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.portname_comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.baudrate_comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()


        for info in QtSerialPort.QSerialPortInfo.availablePorts():
            self.portname_comboBox.addItem(info.portName())

        for baudrate in QtSerialPort.QSerialPortInfo.standardBaudRates():
            self.baudrate_comboBox.addItem(str(baudrate), baudrate)

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Port Name:", self.portname_comboBox)
        #lay.addRow("BaudRate:", self.baudrate_comboBox)
        lay.addRow(buttonBox)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    def get_results(self):
        #return self.portname_comboBox.currentText(), self.baudrate_comboBox.currentData()
        return self.portname_comboBox.currentText(), 9600


class UI(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        # Load the ui file 
        uic.loadUi("sample9.ui", self)
        
        # Define Our Widgets
        self.getbutton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_3")
        self.connectbutton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_2")
        self.portbutton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_5")
        self.disconnectbutton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButton_4")

        # Do something
        self.connectbutton.clicked.connect(self.connectToPort)
        self.portbutton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)
        self.disconnectbutton.clicked.connect(self.disconnectFromPort)
        self.getbutton.clicked.connect(self.getdata)
        
        self.serial = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort(
            self,
            readyRead=self.receive
        )
     


        
    def getdata(self):
        while(1):
            try:    
                print(str2)
                self.serial.write(str2.encode())
                print(str2) 
                time.sleep(3)
                while (self.serial.inWaiting()>0):
                    print("1")
                    serialString=self.serial.readline()
                    print("2")
                    serialString=self.serialString.decode('utf-8')
                    print("3")
                    print(serialString)
            except:
                print("error in get data")
                break

        
        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog()
        if dialog.exec_():
            portname, baudrate = dialog.get_results()
            self.serial.setPortName(portname)
            self.serial.setBaudRate(baudrate)    
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def connectToPort(self):
        self.serial.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def disconnectFromPort(self):
        self.serial.close()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def receive(self):
        while self.serial.canReadLine():
            text = self.serial.readLine().data().decode()
            text = text.rstrip('\r\n')
            self.light_lineEdit.setText(text)
            print(text)
            



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    UIWindow = UI()
    UIWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Arduino Code:**

```
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h> 
#include <Wire.h>
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include "Timer.h"
Timer t;

//SoftwareSerial py_serial(A4,A5); //2 = RX, 3 = Tx
String data;
String cell_type_s;
String charge_cutoff_s;
String discharge_cutoff_s;
String full_charge_voltage_s;
String full_discharge_voltage_s;
String charge_current_limit_s;
String current_limit_s ;
String temp_limit_s;
String total_cycles_s;
String cycle_check_s;
String date_s;
String manufacturer_id_s;
////
int hashid1;
int hashid2;
int hashid3;
int hashid4;
int hashid5;
int hashid6;
int hashid7;
int hashid8;
int hashid9;
int hashid10;
int hashid11;
int hashid12;
int eeAddress = 0;
////
Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;
String TEMPARATUREVALUE;
int temp;
const int oc=5;
const int od=6;
const int s1=10;
const int s2=11;
const int s3=12;
const int s4=13;

const int currentPin=A6;
int sensitivity = 66;
int adcValue= 0;
int offsetVoltage = 2500;
double adcVoltage = 0;
double currentValue = 0;
////
float charge_cutoff=3.65;
float discharge_cutoff=2.5;
float balance_detect=3.4;
float overcharge_release=3.4;
float overdischarge_release=2.9;
float full_charge_voltage=14.0;
float full_discharge_voltage=10.0;
float current_limit=20;
//float current_limit=5;
int temp_limit=50;
int temp_release=45;
float R1=22;
float R2=10;
float b1=0;
float b2=0;
float b3=0;
float b4=0;
float cell1=0;
float cell2=0;
float cell3=0;
float cell4=0;
//const int buzzer=8;
const int buzzer=9;
int x=0;
int y=0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  data= readStringFromEEPROM(0); 
  Serial.println(data);

  hashid1 = data.indexOf('#');
  hashid2 = data.indexOf('#',hashid1+1);
  hashid3 = data.indexOf('#',hashid2+1);
  hashid4 = data.indexOf('#',hashid3+1);
  hashid5 = data.indexOf('#',hashid4+1);
  hashid6 = data.indexOf('#',hashid5+1);
  hashid7 = data.indexOf('#',hashid6+1);
  hashid8 = data.indexOf('#',hashid7+1);
  hashid9 = data.indexOf('#',hashid8+1);
  hashid10 = data.indexOf('#',hashid9+1);
  hashid11 = data.indexOf('#',hashid10+1);
  hashid12 = data.indexOf('#',hashid11+1);
      
      
     // Serial.print("HashId :");
      //Serial.println(hashid1);

      cell_type_s= data.substring(0,hashid1);
      charge_cutoff_s= data.substring(hashid1 + 1,hashid2);
      charge_cutoff=charge_cutoff_s.toFloat();
      discharge_cutoff_s= data.substring(hashid2 + 1,hashid3);
      discharge_cutoff=discharge_cutoff_s.toFloat();
      full_charge_voltage_s= data.substring(hashid3 + 1,hashid4);
      full_charge_voltage=full_charge_voltage_s.toFloat();
      full_discharge_voltage_s = data.substring(hashid4 + 1,hashid5);
      full_discharge_voltage=full_discharge_voltage_s.toFloat();
      charge_current_limit_s = data.substring(hashid5 + 1,hashid6); 
      current_limit_s = data.substring(hashid6 + 1,hashid7);
      current_limit=current_limit_s.toFloat();
      temp_limit_s = data.substring(hashid7 + 1,hashid8);
      temp_limit=temp_limit_s.toFloat();
      total_cycles_s = data.substring(hashid8 + 1,hashid9);
      cycle_check_s = data.substring(hashid9 + 1,hashid10);
      date_s = data.substring(hashid10 + 1,hashid11);
      manufacturer_id_s = data.substring(hashid11 + 1);

//      Serial.println(cell_type_s);
//      Serial.println(charge_cutoff);
//      Serial.println(discharge_cutoff);
//      Serial.println(full_charge_voltage);
//      Serial.println(full_discharge_voltage);
//      Serial.println(charge_current_limit_s);
//      Serial.println(current_limit);
//      Serial.println(temp_limit);
//      Serial.println(total_cycles_s);
//      Serial.println(cycle_check_s);
//      Serial.println(date_s);
//      Serial.println(manufacturer_id_s);
  
  //delay(1000);
  //data = mid;
  //py_serial.begin(9600);
  bmp.begin();
pinMode(oc, OUTPUT);
pinMode(od, OUTPUT);
pinMode(s1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(s2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(s3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(s4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(oc,LOW);
digitalWrite(od,LOW);
digitalWrite(s1,LOW);
digitalWrite(s2,LOW);
digitalWrite(s3,LOW);
digitalWrite(s4,LOW);
digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
t.every(30, serial_data);
}

void loop() 
{
t.update();
overcurrent();
BMP180();
read_cell_voltage();
check_discharging();
check_charging();
balance_check();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////
void read_cell_voltage()
{ 
  //Serial.println("read cell voltage");
cell1=analogRead(A3)*(5.0/1024.0);
cell1= cell1/(R2/(R1+R2));

cell2=analogRead(A2)*(5.0/1024.0);
cell2= cell2/(R2/(R1+R2));

cell3=analogRead(A1)*(5.0/1024.0);
cell3= cell3/(R2/(R1+R2));

cell4=analogRead(A0)*(5.0/1024.0);
cell4= cell4/(R2/(R1+R2));
//Serial.println(cell4);
//Serial.println(cell3);
//Serial.println(cell2);
//Serial.println(cell1);
b4=cell4;  
b3=abs(cell3-cell4);
b2=abs(cell2-cell3);
b1=abs(cell1-cell2);
//Serial.println("Individual Voltages:");
//Serial.println(b4);
//Serial.println(b3);
//Serial.println(b2);
//Serial.println(b1);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
void check_charging()
{ 
  //Serial.println("check charging");
  overcurrent();
  //BMP180();
  if((b4>=charge_cutoff) || (b3>=charge_cutoff) || (b2>=charge_cutoff) || (b1>=charge_cutoff)|| (cell1>=full_charge_voltage)||(temp>temp_limit))//actual 11.4
{ 
  //Serial.println("Over Charge/temperature Protection");
  digitalWrite(oc,LOW);
  if(x==0)
 {
  digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  delay(500);
 }
 x=1;
}
else if((b4<overcharge_release) && (b3<overcharge_release) && (b2<overcharge_release) && (b1<overcharge_release)&&(temp<=temp_release))//&& (cell1<3.4))//actual 11.3
{ 
  overcurrent();
  //BMP180();
  digitalWrite(oc,HIGH);
  x=0;
}
}
void check_discharging()
{
  overcurrent();
  //BMP180();
if((b4<discharge_cutoff) || (b3<discharge_cutoff) || (b2<discharge_cutoff) || (b1<discharge_cutoff) || (cell1<full_discharge_voltage)||(temp>temp_limit)) // actual 7.8
{ //Serial.println("Over Discharge/temperature Protection");
  digitalWrite(od,LOW);
 if(y==0)
 {
  digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
  delay(500);
 }
 y=1;
}
else if((b4>overdischarge_release) && (b3>overdischarge_release) && (b2>overdischarge_release) && (b1>overdischarge_release)&&(temp<=temp_release))//&& (cell1<3.123))
{ 
 overcurrent();
 //BMP180();
 digitalWrite(od,HIGH);
 y=0;
}
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void balance_check()
{
//Serial.println("balance check");
overcurrent();
//Serial.println("Balance Check:");
//Serial.println(b4);
//Serial.println(b3);
//Serial.println(b2);
//Serial.println(b1);
  if(b4>balance_detect)
{ digitalWrite(s4,HIGH);
 //Serial.println("b4");
}
else
{digitalWrite(s4,LOW);
}
if(b3>balance_detect)
{ digitalWrite(s3,HIGH);
//Serial.println("b3");
}
else{digitalWrite(s3,LOW);
} 
if(b2>balance_detect)
{ digitalWrite(s2,HIGH);
  //Serial.println("b2");
}
else{digitalWrite(s2,LOW);
}
if(b1>balance_detect)
{ digitalWrite(s1,HIGH);
//Serial.println("b1");
}
else{digitalWrite(s1,LOW);}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void current()
{
  //Serial.println("current==");
 adcValue = analogRead(currentPin);
 adcVoltage = (adcValue / 1024.0) * 5000;
 //currentValue = ((adcVoltage - offsetVoltage) / sensitivity);
  currentValue = abs((adcVoltage - offsetVoltage) / sensitivity);
  //Serial.print("Raw Sensor Value = " );
  //Serial.println(adcValue);
  
//  Serial.print(" Voltage(mV) = ");
//  Serial.println(adcVoltage);
//  Serial.print("Current = ");
//  Serial.println(currentValue);
}
//////////////////////////////
void overcurrent()
{
 current();
 while(currentValue>=current_limit) 
 {  
    digitalWrite(oc,LOW);
    digitalWrite(od,LOW);
    if((currentValue>=0.0)&&(currentValue<=18))
    {break;}
    //Serial.println("overcurrent is activated");
    delay(10000);
    current();   
 }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void BMP180()
{
//Serial.print("Temparature=="); 
TEMPARATUREVALUE = String(bmp.readTemperature());
temp=TEMPARATUREVALUE.toInt();
temp=abs(temp);
//Serial.print(temp);
//Serial.println("C");  
 }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  void serial_data()
  {
    while(Serial.available())
    {

     if(Serial.available() > 0)
     {
      data =Serial.readString();
      Serial.println(data);
      //EEPROM.put(0, data);
      if(data=="getdata")
        {
          String eeprom_data= readStringFromEEPROM(0); 
          //Serial.println(eeprom_data);
          //delay(100);
          //writeString(eeprom_data);
          delay(100);
        }
       else
       {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < EEPROM.length() ; i++) 
         {EEPROM.write(i, 0);}
          digitalWrite(buzzer,HIGH);
          writeStringToEEPROM(0,data);
          //Serial.println("EEPROM Updated!");
       }
    }
    }
 }

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 void writeStringToEEPROM(int addrOffset, const String &strToWrite)
{
  byte len = strToWrite.length();
  EEPROM.write(addrOffset, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {EEPROM.write(addrOffset + 1 + i, strToWrite[i]);}
}
String readStringFromEEPROM(int addrOffset)
{
  //Serial.println("BMS Settings!!!!");
  int newStrLen = EEPROM.read(addrOffset);
  char data[newStrLen + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < newStrLen; i++)
  {data[i] = EEPROM.read(addrOffset + 1 + i);}
  data[newStrLen] = '\0'; // !!! NOTE !!! Remove the space between the slash "/" and "0" (I've added a space because otherwise there is a display bug)
  return String(data);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void writeString(String stringData) 
{ // Used to serially push out a String with Serial.write()

  for (int i = 0; i < stringData.length(); i++)
  {
    Serial.write(stringData[i]);   // Push each char 1 by 1 on each loop pass
  }

}// end writeString
```

**GUI PIC:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMA9b.png)
[This is GUI. When I press the Get data button the GUI is going to crash.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKUFp.png)